# Search a form by matching two fields in form in access

Tags: vba, ms-access, search, module, combobox

I have a form in MS access named `frmBullList` which has one field named `TYPE` and other field `LOCATION`. I have separate table for `LOCATION` which is connected with `tblBullList`.

I want search for a record where both fields match.

Let's say I want to search for red bulls (`TYPE`) in US (`LOCATION`). The results would show only red bulls in US.

Thanks

Comment: *"I have separate table for LOCATION which is connected with tblBullList."* How are they connected?

Comment: Seems you missed the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: it is connected with a one to many relationship.

Comment: @MoodyA Pulling teeth: on what fields? Not read my links?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your table LOCATION has 3 fields:

```
LocationID
LocationName
TypeID
```

and the table TYPE has 2 fields:

```
TypeID
TypeName
```

If this is true than create for your cmbType combo event:

```vb
    Private Sub cmbType_AfterUpdate()
        If isnull(cmbType) Then
            Me.Filter = ""
            Me.FilterOn = False
        Else
            Me.Filter = "TypeID = " & cmbType.column(0)
            Me.FilterOn = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Your should set these properties (you can set them in Property window as well):

```vb
    Private Sub Form_Load()
        Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM LOCATION"
        Me.txtLocation.ControlSource = "LocationName"
        Me.cmbType.RowSource = "SELECT TypeID, LocationName FROM TYPE"
        Me.cmbType.BoundColumn = 1
        Me.cmbType.ColumnCount = 2
        Me.cmbType.ColumnWidths = "0;"
    End Sub
```

I hope I did not forget anything. I have not tested it.

Comment: As [access-vba] misses the lang-vb code hint and no other tag (see tags decription to check) refernces lang-vb (or any other) in this question, no default syntax highlighting activated, To turn on add a [code hint](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

Comment: Nice. I did it. Thank you.

Comment: And if you wonder about that ugly highlighting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55753980/adodb-execute-sql-command-timeout), that is caused by more than one code hint (vba and sql) , then a default highlighting is used, what not recognizes quotes as comments, but string-literal. Manual lang setting fixes that.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I didn't put up my question really good. my database has 2 tables tblBullList and tblLocation. these two tables are connected with LocationID . Whereas TYPE is a field within tblBullList.  I have a splitform   named frmBullList. I have two combo on top....one combo is cboType & other is cboLocation.  Hope it's much clear now.